# can't reach page while export pdf/downloading file from localhost

Tags: php, yii2, localhost, pdf-generation

I want to export data tables to PDF.

I'm using Yii2 Framework, PHP version 7.3 and use Mpdf plugin.

I think the code is correct, because it doesn't show any error information when I click the button to export  to PDF, the page spends a long time loading, and in the end, it just displays "can't reach the page".

This problem also happens when I try to download files from my local directory.

Here is the code:

The controller:

```
public function actionExportPdf()
{
    $searchModel = new BelanjaSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $html = $this->renderPartial('_pdf', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
    $mpdf = new \mpdf('c', 'A4', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
}
```

pdf.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Print</title>
    <style>
        .page {
            padding: 2cm;
        }

        table {
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        table td,
        table th {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        table th {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <h1>Belanja</h1>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Jenis Belanja</th>
                <th>Subjenis Belanja</th>
                <th>Barang</th>
                <th>Jumlah</th>
                <th>Satuan</th>
                <th>Harga</th>
                <th>Jumlah Harga</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $no = 1;
            foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $bar) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?= $no++ ?></th>
                    <th><?= $bar->jenis_belanja ?></th>
                    <th><?= $bar->subjenis_belanja ?></th>
                    <th><?= $bar->barang_belanja ?></th>
                    <th><?= $bar->jumlah_barang ?></th>
                    <th><?= $bar->satuan_barang ?></th>
                    <th><?= $bar->harga_satuan ?></th>
                    <th><?= $bar->jumlah_harga ?></th>
                
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: can't reach the page]

I already checked the server connection, and it's all good, there's no problem.

Comment: Why you don't have any return in your action controller? IMO to render a page you must have somthing like `return $this->render`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything, just exiting, so the browser will wait for a response until the value of `timeout` is reached and then let you know that it couldn't reach the server, which is the conclusion that it reached because it never got a response.

Since you are using **mpdf** directly, you should be able to use the [`Output`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html) method to return the PDF data to the browser directly as the response.

```php
public function actionExportPdf()
{
    $searchModel = new BelanjaSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $html = $this->renderPartial('_pdf', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
    $mpdf = new \mpdf('c', 'A4', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    // Change the next two lines
    return $mpdf->Output();
}
```

Note that I haven't tried this, I use the [Kartik Yii2 MPDF wrapper](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf) instead of using MPDF directly, but what you have should work *once you return the data*.

If that does not work, you could update your project to use the wrapper, then construct the PDF like a widget, there is an example [here](https://demos.krajee.com/mpdf#widget-usage), in your case it would be something like this:

```php
use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;
...

public function actionExportPdf()
{
    $searchModel = new BelanjaSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $html = $this->renderPartial('_pdf', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);

    $pdf = new Pdf([
        // set to use core fonts only
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,  // Or Pdf::MODE_UTF8
        //Name for the file
        'filename' => Yii::t('app', 'document.pdf'),
        // A4 paper format
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        // portrait orientation
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
        // stream to browser inline
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
        // your html content input
        'content' => $html,
        // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
        // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting
        'cssFile' => '@cssPath/pdf-document.css',
        // any css to be embedded if required
        'cssInline' => '',
        // set mPDF properties on the fly
        'options' => [
            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'document.pdf'),
            'autoScriptToLang' => true,
            'autoLangToFont' => true
        ],
        // call mPDF methods on the fly
        'methods' => [
            'SetHeader'=>[$document->getNamei18n()],
            'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
        ],
    ]);

    return $pdf->render();
}
```

Kartik has a [page with a lot of examples here](https://demos.krajee.com/mpdf).

Comment: thanks for the answer, really helps me. I change it using Kartik MPDF wrapper

Comment: @Cokelalat great, if the answer helped you, consider marking it as accepted and/or up voting it, check the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to see why that matters.